# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol referenced in function main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, assembly, x86-64

Am trying to run my simple assembly code in C++.I have only two files ".cpp" file and ".asm" file. On compiling it gives an error (see below ).I would appreciate if anyone could help...:)

This is my "main.cpp" file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM(); 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

cout<<"value is:"<<GetValueFromASM()<<endl;
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Also i have a simple "asm.asm" file

```
.code
   GetValueFromASM proc
   mov rax,3254
   ret
   GetValueFromASM endp
end
```

When  try to build i get this error :

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GetValueFromASM referenced in             
function main

1>..\visual studio 2012\Projects\AllAssembly\x64\Debug\AllAssembly.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried go to PROPERTIES->LINKS->ADDITIONAL LIBRARY DIRECTORIES and change the path
but it didn't work.

I tried also go to LINKER->SYSTEM->SUBSYSTEM and Select "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)" or 
"Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)" but neither one worked. Can anyone help !!..BIG THANKS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

extern "C" implies a leading underscore (c-style function naming). Just prefix your function in .asm file and it'll start linking.

UPD: if your project does not build, be sure, you included MASM build customizations: go to project Context Menu -> Build Customizations... -> check the tickbox for masm (.targets, .props).

Then go to properties of you .asm file and select Item Type as 'Microsoft Macro Assembler'.

Comment: i tried changing the function name from GetValueFromASM to _GetValueFromASM ..but it didnt work either !

Comment: See my update - Visual Studio 2012 do not include MASM build customizations by default - you have to enable them.

Comment: @105tNoMatter you should accept the answer that worked for you

Comment: @Arty, everything is done, but still the same error occurs, VC++ 2013

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov, are you on x86 or x64? Can you provide some snippets from your masm code?

Comment: @Arty Yeah, i've solved my trouble. I was on x86 arch and VS2013. The problem was that the main module was cpp and asm was as secondary. I chose '.model flat, stdcall', and it caused an error, changing to '.model flat, c' helped.

Answer (score 2):

I confused it with 32bit. :(

So this should work for 64bit.

```
section .code
global GetValueFromASM

GetValueFromASM:
    ...
```

Comment: i tried change the function name from GetValueFromASM to    _GetValueFromASM ..but it didnt work,can you explain the alternative way..I mean what you mean by "flagging the proc as C"..thnx

Comment: Did you try this? Making the function namne global? Which assembler are you using?

Comment: Am still in trouble man..can you give the complete new version of "asm.asm" suggesting the changes i should make.@Devolus

Comment: Which assembler are you using? yasm? And your C project is also 64 bit?

Comment: yeah i declared it global..am using visual studio 2012(I guess this is what u asked coz i confuse between assembler and compiller)..How to know if it is yasm/masm etc ?

Comment: I'm not sure iof your environment is properly setup so here is a link which explains it in detail: http://www.sciencezero.org/index.php?title=How_to_write_x64_assembly_functions_in_Visual_C%2B%2B

Comment: Thanx..i'll have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

No Changes i made to the codes.I just changed some configurations as "Arty" suggests.

Here is How :
Right click your project->Go to Build Customization -> check MASM -> Click OK
Then go to properties of your .asm file and select Item Type as 'Microsoft Macro Assembler'.

You Done!!..Thanks to Arty & Devolus for the help.

Can be helpful For similar problem:
http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/setting-up-visual-studio-10-for-masm32-programming/

Comment: VisualStudio 2008 (and I would assume later versions as well) has this nice feature that you don't need to customize the build step. Just create an empty asm file or use an existing one and use "add existing Item" in your project. It then automatically provides the build step configuration. I use this because it's more convenient then setting it up myself. :)